# How do I use the Rails helper link_to RESTfully in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I basically want to use link_to to link to the index method of a controller.  I tried:

```
<%= link_to 'Recipes', Recipe %>
```

but that outputs:

```
<a href="/recipes/Recipe">Recipes</a>
```

Which is clearly not right, if it left off that last bit it would do exactly what I want it to.  I thought that with RESTful stuff I somehow would start to leave out the action or something like that.  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the restful routes, the majority of the time you're expected to call a helper method to generate the route.

eg:

```
link_to 'Recipes', recipes_path
```

There is an optimization where you can just pass in a recipe object, and it will call the helper method for you behind the scenes: eg:

```
link_to 'Recipe X', @recipe
```

is the same as

```
link_to 'Recipe X', recipe_path(@recipe)
```

However, it's just a special case.

What you are doing is passing *The recipe class itself*, not a valid recipe object. As rails doesn't know to handle this, as a fallback it just calls `.to_s` on whatever you've given it, and then gives that to `recipe_path`, which is why you see the strange URL.

#### Tip: Use the `_path` helper methods rather than the `_url` methods.

`_url` gives you a full URL such as `http://stackoverflow.com/recipes/5` whereas `_path` just gives you `/recipes/5`.
The problem with the full URL is that a lot of the time in production your rails app is running as a mongrel sitting behind a load balancer, so it thinks it's host name is actually `1.2.3.4` (or whatever the internal LAN IP is) rather than the real URL, and so will serve broken links.

Comment: Your first example should use recipes_path - you want the index action.